# Problem with refreshing a ListView when I add an item from an other window (ObservableCollection)

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, observablecollection

I have a problem with adding item in my ListView from an another windows, its not added to the list.
I am trying to add an item to my ListView that is in my MainWindow from the window WindowTodAddANewBus and I when I add it I would like the MainWindow to be refresh automatically.

Definition of my List in MainWindow.xaml.cs with ObservableCollection

```
public static List<Bus> buses = new List<Bus>();
public static ObservableCollection<Bus> myCollection { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Bus>(buses);
```

In the constructor:

```
public MainWindow()
       {
           InitializeComponent();
           myListView.ItemsSource = buses;
       }
```

When I am adding a new item in WindowToAddANewBus.xaml.cs

```
Bus b1 = new Bus(myLicenseNum, date);
MainWindow.myCollection.Add(b1);
```

I don't know if I used well the ObservableCollection..

If you could help me pls!!
Thank you

Comment: This is an suggestion to your code example in general, but you should look into using something like MvvmLight and binding to the model than setting stuff in code behind, it will make things easier in the long run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set your `ItemsSource` to your `myCollection` property and not `buses`.

To add some context an `ObservableCollection` does **not** notify changes to the collection you pass in to the constructor, this is simply a way to place a load of items inside the collection when creating it. It does however notify changes when it's underlying collection changes (e.g. `Add`, `Remove`, `Clear`, etc.). Given this I don't think you even need the `buses` property at all, you can simply just use your `myCollection` property.

Basically change your constructor to:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    myListView.ItemsSource = myCollection;
}
```

#### Possible improvements to general approach

To take things a little bit further you may wish to avoid using a `static` property entirely as things can certainly get a little messy around these parts. I would suggest looking at either passing your `myCollection` property over to the `WindowToAddANewBus` when you create/show it, or better still have that `WindowToAddANewBus` class return a `Bus` when it is closed.

Comment: Ok thank you!! But how I can convert ObservalCollection to type List because I have this function that receives a List<Bus> to initialise my list with 10 buses, or I must do a new function InitializeBus(ObservableCollection myCollection) ?

Comment: @Elish you could probably just change the type in your function to be `IEnumerable<Bus>` instead of `List<Bus>` although it is difficult to say for sure without seeing the function